# unable to connect to server: connection failed: connection refused is the server running on that host accepting tcp/ip connections?

Tags: server, postgresql, pgadmin

I have postgres 13.10 and PGAdmin4 7.1 installed on Ubuntu 22.04

In PGAdmin4 UI, I want to "add new server" with these configurations

```
name
postgres-local

username
postgres

pw
postgres

hostanme / address
127.0.0.1

port
5432

server group
Servers
```

so I have run in my terminal

```
sudo -i -u postgres

psql


ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

Then I login into PGAdmin4, try to add new server inserting the cofigurations above, but as I click on save I get this error

```
unable to connect to server: connection failed: connection refused is the server running on that host accepting tcp/ip connections?
```

What could be the problem?

### What I already tried

I have checked that postgres is running correctly via `sudo service postgresql status`.

[image]

I have already tryed to

edit file `/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf` uncommenting 
`listen_addresses = 'localhost'` 
and changing it into 
`listen_addresses = '*'`

edit file `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` changing lines

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32               md5
```

to

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

restarting postgres

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

But I had no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you made sure that postgres is running on that port?

```
sudo netstat -lntp | grep postgres
```

Have you made sure that the firewall is not blocking that port?

```
sudo ufw allow 5432
```

Comment: Actually by running `sudo netstat -lntp | grep postgres` I found out postgres was runnng under port 5433. I was going to uninstall and reinstall all. Thanks!!